# Cannot login to SQL database using pyodbc, login failure

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Has anyone seen this error before?:

```
ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "TC" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060) (SQLDriverConnect); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Cannot open database "TC" requested by the login. The login failed. (4060)')
```

I have verified my credentials and they are 100% correct. As well as, I am using:

python 3.9.7

pyodbc 4.0.0

and when I use:

```
[x for x in pyodbc.drivers() if x.startswith("ODBC Driver")]
```

I get:

```
['ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
```

and I'm using SSMS 2014 so ODBC Driver 11 should support that. I am lost as to why this error keeps popping up for my connection string, my connection string is:

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + database + ';UID=' + username + ';PWD=' + password)
```

So I've verified everything I can think of to this point and it all seems correct, what could the issue be?

Comment: Check the SQL Server's logs and get the true authentication error; if you don't understand that error, [edit] your question to include that error.

Comment: Is this an SQL Server Authentication login or a Windows Authentication login?

Comment: @Charlieface This should be an SQL Server Authentication login if I'm using credentials, no? Because the way my access to SSMS is set up is that when I log in I have a windows login. However, I used a similar connection string in VBA and it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Looking at the error code, sounds like either permissions issue re the database you want to connect to, or the database is set to `SINGLE_USER`. Is there any more information in the SQL Server Logs?

Comment: @Charlieface Yeah, so at my work they have the logs set to a special permission which I've been trying to gain access to in SSMS. I'm kinda new to this but its super fun learning all this so I'll try to find out what the logs say and report back. I appreciate all the help so far from you and Larnu

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the driver to explicitly use v11

```
pyodbc.connect(driver='{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}', 
server='Server', database='TC', uid='id',pwd='pass')
```

Comment: I believe it to be something with my SSMS permissions at work, I tried this and received the same error. I appreciate the suggestion though because I'm really trying to learn.